# Repeating rows in SAS

Tags: sas

In SAS, how do I repeat the first 4 rows of a variable until the last observation? It should look something like this:

```
DATA Have; 
   INPUT HAVE$ ; 
   DATALINES; 
A
B
C
D
.
.
.
.
; 
PROC PRINT; RUN;

DATA want; 
   INPUT WANT$ ; 
   DATALINES; 
A
B
C
D
A
B
C
D
; 
PROC PRINT; RUN;
```

Comment: This question doesn't seem very useful the way it's currently asked.  What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will use your current dataset HAVE to:
1) Read in the total number of rows to output
2  store the first 4 variables in an array VARS(4).
3) Use the mod function to loop through the values 0-3 (+1) to pull back the array element and output in a loop.

This will work for the top 4 rows of any dataset and output the required number of rows from the original :)

```
DATA Have; 
INPUT HAVE$ ; 
DATALINES; 
A
B
C
D
.
.
.
.
;
proc print; RUN;

DATA WANT;
array VARS(4) $;
do i = 1 to 4; 
  set HAVE(obs=4) nobs=n;
  VARS(i)=HAVE;
end;

do j = 0 to n-1;
  NEW_HAVE=VARS(mod(j,4)+1);
  keep NEW_HAVE;
  output;
end;
proc print; run;
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to do the job :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lag` function to fill in the blanks when it hits those missing values. `lag` is a special function and acts funny in `if` statements, so it's better to create a new variable holding that value at the start of the program, then drop it at the end.

Create a new variable, `last4obs` and assign it the lagged value of `have`. Then, when `have` is missing, assign `have` to the value of `last4obs`.

```
data want;
    set have;

    last4obs = lag4(have);
    if(missing(have) ) then have = last4obs;

    drop last4obs;
run;
```

The resulting dataset will look like this (without dropping `last4obs`):

```
obs  have last4obs
1    A  
2    B  
3    C  
4    D  
5    A    A
6    B    B
7    C    C
8    D    D
```